# Horizontal menu being chopped off

Tags: html, css, joomla, styles

Can anyone tell me why the header menu is being cut off?

It is the pink menu I'm talking about. I'm using Joomla 1.7 and the IceMenu extension, but for some reason the menu is being chopped off. Also, the actual hover color of the pink menu. Does anyone know how to change that?

http://ream.wsidwdev.com/our-work

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hover color of the pink menu in line 82 of this file:

http://ream.wsidwdev.com/modules/mod_icemegamenu/themes/default/css/default_icemegamenu.css

With regards to the pink menu being cut off I'm not sure what you mean. I can see in your code that the Ul with an ID of 'icemegamenu' is trying to be absolutely positioned but you haven't actually set it to have 'position:absolute'.

Answer (score 0):

For the positioning of your pink menu, you've declared the position with the `top` and `left` properties, but you don't have the position property.

Wherever you want that menu to be positioned it has to be `relative` to the parent element it is inside of, unless you `absolute`ly position it to another place altogether. I don't see how it's being chopped off. There are 4 list items in code and they all display on the screen.